# Why is not allowed to use n_jobs at SKLearn's Support Vector Regressor?

Tags: scikit-learn, regression, svm

According to [the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVR.html), using the parameter `n_jobs` on a SVR is not supported.

On the other hand, and again from the docs, that parameter [is supported](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestRegressor) at other types of regressor.

1. Why is this?
2. What is the best method to speed up a regressor in that case?

This is the error traceback I'm getting:

```
regressor = SVR(kernel='rbf', C=1, n_jobs=-1)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'n_jobs'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've got some suggestions in relation to your second question.

`SVR` is slow for lots of samples (tens of thousands), so one option is to resample your data down to a smaller representative sample using stratified sampling.

Look into `scikit-learn-intelex` - if applicable to your platform it will give you a performance boost in terms of speed.

Below I outline some options that approximate `SVR` and perform faster.

> 2. What is the best method to speed up a regressor in that case?

To speed up *support vector* regression specifically, you could try running an algorithm that approximates it using a linear model. The snippet below approximates the effect of an RBF kernel using `Nystroem`, and feeds those RBF features into a `LinearSVR`. Computation time for `LinearSVR` scales linearly with the number of samples, making it faster than `SVR`.

You can adjust these primary factors to trade accuracy for speed:

- `n_components=` in `Nystroem`
- Replacing `Nystroem` with `RBFSampler` (latter is generally faster but may be less accurate)
- `tol=` can also be increased to trade accuracy for speed. This also applies to various regularisation parameters.
- Could try replacing `LinearSVR` with `SGDRegressor(loss='epsilon_insensitive')`. It might not converge as quickly, but it gives you another set of dials to tune if wanted.

```py
from sklearn.kernel_approximation import Nystroem, RBFSampler
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVR

from sklearn.pipeline import make_pipeline

#np.random.seed(0) #makes example reproducible

rbf_svr_approx = make_pipeline(
    Nystroem(kernel='rbf', n_components=100, n_jobs=-1),
    LinearSVR(),
)
```